# Perfect Binding and Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to leave a 1/8” (0,125 in) white
strip to the right and left of the spine to allow perfect adhesion between the glue and the paper in indesign.

I cannot set this please help

Answer (score 2):

In a *Facing Pages* InDesign document....

Choose `Layout > Margins and Columns...`

Set The `Inside` margin to your desired gutter width. Then, when designing, do *not* put anything inside that margin.